# AdvancedDataGrid Flex Analogue

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, advanceddatagrid

Could you suggest me please any Flex 3 (MX) component, which works like Flex's AdvancedDataGrid but much easier?

I need only hierarchical view for data and ability to easily customize it's view. Simplest ever tree with depth of 2, with no borders and chrome, which just works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your options for hierarchy are tree and advanced datagrid.
Check out rendererproviders for advanced data grid. You specify which renderer to use based on the hierarchy depth.  Turn off ADG headers, row colors, and borders if you want no chrome.

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid 
    id="myDatagrid">
<mx:columns>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn />
</mx:columns>
<mx:rendererProviders>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider 
            renderer="com.somepath.someclass"
            columnSpan="0"
            columnIndex="0"
            depth="1"/>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider
            renderer="com.somepath.someotherclass"
            columnIndex="0"
            columnSpan="0"
            depth="2"/>
</mx:rendererProviders>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid >
```